# request.getparameter is not giving correct answer for a array of strings

Tags: java, servlets

this is my first servlet which is passing contents to next servlet..

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    String s1=request.getParameter("t123");
    String s2=request.getParameter("t2");

    try
    {
        Connection conn=dao.DataDAP.getConn();
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select * from "+s1+" where Brand like '%"+s2+"%'");

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();


        out.println("<html><body><center>");
        out.println("<h1>Searched Products</h1>");
        out.println("<hr>");

        out.println("<table border=5>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>Product Id</td>");
        out.println("<td>Product Name</td>");
        out.println("<td>Product Category</td>");
        out.println("<td>No. Of Items</td>");
        out.println("<td>Brand</td>");
        out.println("<td>Image</td>");
        out.println("<td>Price</td>");
        out.println("<td>Description</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");



        while(rs.next())
        {
            String pi=rs.getString(1);
            String pn=rs.getString(2);
            String pc=rs.getString(3);
            String no=rs.getString(4);
            String br=rs.getString(5);
            String im=rs.getString(6);
            int pr=rs.getInt(7);
            String pd=rs.getString(8);

            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>"+pi+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+pn+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+pc+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+no+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+br+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+im+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+pr+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+pd+"</td>");

            out.println("<td><a href='update?pi="+pi+"&&pn="+pn+"&&pc="+pc+"&&no="+no+"&&br="+br+"&&im="+im+"&&pr"+pr+"&&pd="+pd+"&&table="+s1+"'>Update Product</a></td>");
            out.println("</tr>");
        }


        out.println("</table>");


        out.println("</center></body></html>");

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }



}


}
```

and i am taking all data in next servlet but when the product name is samsung galaxy grand2 it only shows samsung in update form and also in amount it shows null...

```
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        String productid=request.getParameter("pi");
        String productname=request.getParameter("pn");
        String productcategory=request.getParameter("pc");
        String noofitems=request.getParameter("no");
        String brand=request.getParameter("br");
        String productimage=request.getParameter("im");
        String productamount=request.getParameter("pr");
        String productdescription=request.getParameter("pd");
        String table=request.getParameter("table");


        out.println("<html><body><center><h1>Update Form</h1>");

        out.println("<form action=update2>");

        out.println("<table>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>Product ID: </td>");
        out.println("<td><input type=text name=t1 value="+productid+" disabled=disabled></td>");
        out.println("<input type=hidden name=t1 value="+productid+">");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>Product Name: </td>");
        out.println("<td><input type=text name=t2 value="+productname+" ></td>");

        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>Product Category: </td>");
        out.println("<td><input type=text name=t3 value="+productcategory+" disabled=disabled></td>");
        out.println("<input type=hidden name=t3 value="+productcategory+">");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>No. of Items: </td>");
        out.println("<td><input type=text name=t4 value="+noofitems+"></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>Brand: </td>");
        out.println("<td><input type=text name=t5 value="+brand+" disabled=disabled></td>");
        out.println("<input type=hidden name=t5 value="+brand+">");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>Product Image: </td>");
        out.println("<td><input type=text name=t6 value="+productimage+" disabled=disabled></td>");
        out.println("<input type=hidden name=t6 value="+productimage+">");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>Product Amount: </td>");
        out.println("<td><input type=text name=t7 value="+productamount+"></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>Product Description: </td>");
        out.println("<td><textarea style=height:150px;width:200px; name=t8 value="+productdescription+"</textarea> disabled=disabled></td>");
        out.println("<input type=hidden name=t8 value="+productdescription+"></textarea>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td><input type=submit value=Update></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<input type=hidden name=t9 value="+table+">");

        out.println("</table>");

        out.println("</form>");

        out.println("</center></body></html>");
```

Comment: try replacing spaces with `%20`. Because you are using plain Servlet, you need to handle character escaping by yourself.

Comment: where do i replace space plzz elaborate????

Comment: Actually the browser will escape words for you. So you don't need replacing spaces with %20

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`String[] strings = request.getParameterValues("pi")`
and then you should have all the words

Comment: bro this doesnot work as when i display it.It shows [Ljava.lang.String;@1b94f78 instead of productname.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing all the parameters in the url why just dont store the parameters in an `Map` and pass the `Map` to the second servlet

something like this

```
Map map = new HashMap();
while(rs.next())
        {
            map.put("pi",rs.getString(1));
            map.put("pn",rs.getString(2));
            map.put("pc",rs.getString(3));
            map.put("no",rs.getString(4));
            map.put("br",rs.getString(5));
            map.put("im",rs.getString(6));
            map.put("pr",rs.getInt(7));
            map.put("pd",rs.getString(8));
        }

request.setAttribute("map", map);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/servleturl").include(request, response);
```

Then in the second servlet retrieve the values from the map

```
HashMap map = (HashMap) request.getAttribute("map");
String pi = map.get("pi").toString();
```

Comment: bro.. this doesnot work in my scenerio as i have to again pass it onto next servlet...suggest any other solution plzzzzz